# Pygame create a fresh screen

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

Basically i have been stuck for hours trying to create a blank template when the user clicks new game. I tell the code to then cancel the while loop and use the Background.fill() function to create a blank screen but it doesn't work. Here is my code.

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
from pygame import *

def text():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 40)
    surfacefont = font.render("Tower Defense", True, black)
    surfaceR = surfacefont.get_rect()
    surfaceR.center = (400,50)
    Background.blit(surfacefont, surfaceR)

    text = font.render("Start game", True, black)
    textpos = surfacefont.get_rect()
    textpos.center = (425,200)
    Background.blit(text, textpos)

    text = font.render("Exit Game", True, black)
    textpos = surfacefont.get_rect()
    textpos.center = (435,260)
    Background.blit(surfacefont, surfaceR)
    Background.blit(text, textpos)
    pygame.display.update()

def button():
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if 285+205 > pos[0] > 285 and 175+50 > pos[1] > 175:
        pygame.draw.rect(Background, (100,100,100),(263,175,250,50))
        if click[0] == 1:
            cancelLoop()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(Background, white,(285,175,205,50))

    if 278+220 > pos[0] > 278 and 234+50 > pos[1] > 234: 
        pygame.draw.rect(Background, (100,100,100),(278,234,220,50))
        if click[0] == 1:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(Background, white,(278,234,220,50))

def cancelLoop():
    global intro
    intro = 0
    runGame()

def runGame():
    Background.fill(red)

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
Background = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tower Defense")
intro = 1
while intro == 1:
    Background.fill(white)
    button()
    text()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == quit:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: You only should use one of either `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` because they do basically the same thing. Either one works but `update()` is optimized for software displays and thus recommended for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The  problem is that you are effectively exiting your game when you call `intro == 0`, since you cancelled your while loop. As a result the program will just end after the intro. Instead of making a while loop for just your intro you could make one main loop, where the `runGame()` function is also called, or you could make separate loops for your intro and the actual game.
This would be how I would personally write it:

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
from pygame import *

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
Background = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tower Defense")

def text():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 40)
    surfacefont = font.render("Tower Defense", True, black)
    surfaceR = surfacefont.get_rect()
    surfaceR.center = (400,50)
    Background.blit(surfacefont, surfaceR)

    text = font.render("Start game", True, black)
    textpos = surfacefont.get_rect()
    textpos.center = (425,200)
    Background.blit(text, textpos)

    text = font.render("Exit Game", True, black)
    textpos = surfacefont.get_rect()
    textpos.center = (435,260)
    Background.blit(surfacefont, surfaceR)
    Background.blit(text, textpos)
    pygame.display.update()

def button():
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if 285+205 > pos[0] > 285 and 175+50 > pos[1] > 175:
        pygame.draw.rect(Background, (100,100,100),(263,175,250,50))
        if click[0] == 1:
            runGame()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(Background, white,(285,175,205,50))

    if 278+220 > pos[0] > 278 and 234+50 > pos[1] > 234: 
        pygame.draw.rect(Background, (100,100,100),(278,234,220,50))
        if click[0] == 1:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(Background, white,(278,234,220,50))

def runGame():
    Background.fill(red)

intro = 1
while intro == 1:
    Background.fill(white)
    button()
    text()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == quit:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```